# Doctrine 2, how to get a property in a left join result set?

Tags: join, symfony, doctrine-orm, junction-table

Symfony 2, Doctrine 2.1.

I've got 3 entities, one of them intermediate (join table). Let's say it's SomeObject, SomeProperty and ObjectProperties.

**Problem:** I can't get the value of SomeProperty 'name' property. Here's the code:

```
[...]    
class SomeObject
{
 /**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

  /**
   *
   * @var ObjectProperties $objectProperties
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ObjectProperties", mappedBy="object_id", cascade={"all"})
   */
  private $objectProperties;
[...]
```

---

```
[...]
class SomeProperty
{
 /**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ObjectProperties", mappedBy="property_id", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $id;


  /**
   * @var string $name
   *   
  */

private $name;//I NEED TO GET VALUE OF $name
[...]
```

---

```
[...]
class ObjectProperties
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SomeObject", inversedBy="id", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $object_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SomeProperty", inversedBy="id", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="property_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $property_id;
[...]
```

---

Setters and getters as usual.

In my controller I've got something along the lines of:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('SomeTestBundle:SomeObject')->find($id);
[...]
$props = $entity->getObjectProperties();
    foreach ($props as $prop){
        echo '---------------------------<br>';
        var_dump($prop->getPropertyId()->getName());
    }
```

---

Now, getName() gives me null result, but if i replace it with getId it works as expected. Same if I try to use it in a form class. Is it because there is no doctrine association between SomeProperty->name and ObjectProperties?

I think I don't quite get the way doctrine is supposed to work. I thought that only property_id and object_id are needed in a junction table, otherwise it doesn't make much sense for me, because SomeProperty serves as a dictionary table, so I could change SomeProperty->name in one place.

I'm seriously stuck with it. Is it some sort of configuration option that is lacking or am I generally not getting the bigger picture?

Comment: In ObjectProperties, why did you add '_id' after your property names? You should name them $object and $property. Plus, the JoinColumns annotations are useless.

Comment: Well, made it work by using @Column annotation, will post answer in 6 hours.

Comment: Aaaaargh, I think you overcomplicated. You just needed to remove this '_id' suffix

Comment: True, but it probably wouldn't work anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider it a typo - I've made it work by adding missing @Column annotation in SomeProperty class:

```
   /**
   * @var string $name
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")   
   */   
  private $name;
```

Don't know why I missed it in the first place... I guess "Experience is something you get, after you need it."